# Searching across multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, search

I'm trying to make a search feature that will search multiple columns to find a keyword based match. For example when the user enters a keyword to search, i need to conduct a search across five category columns and return the corresponding row names of all the rows that contain the keyword in either of its category columns. The code is as follows:

```
   <?php
    mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("could not connect.");
  mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("could not find database.");
  $result = "";
  //collect info from database
  if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
      $searchq = $_POST['search'];
      $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchq);
//SQL query
      $query = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM institutes WHERE category1 LIKE '%$searchq%' OR category2 LIKE '%$searchq%' OR category3 LIKE '%$searchq%' OR category4 LIKE '%$searchq%' OR category5 LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die("No records found.");
      $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
      if($count == 0)
      {
          $output = "There's no search result";
      }
      else {
          while($array = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
    ?>
        <li><?php echo $array['name'];?></li>
    <?php
    }
  ?>
      }
  }
  </ul>
```

I have tried various ways to search but every time, either there is an error or the code just returns every row name irrespective of conditions. a solutions to the problem will be appreciated.

Comment: Full text search may be the best option. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: are you sure your `$searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchq);` line working properly?

Comment: Hmmm, a) have you tried to echo `$searchq` afther the preg_replace line? b) If errors occur, what do the say? The general approach and the SQL seem OK to me (without having tried it or knowing your data...).

Comment: The elephant in the room is the long since deprecated mysql_ API... So see about that, and see about normalisation!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("could not connect.");
  mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("could not find database.");
  $result = "";
  //collect info from database
  if(isset($_POST['search'])&& $_POST['search'] != "")) {
      $searchq = $_POST['search'];
      $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

//SQL query
      $query = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM institutes WHERE category1 LIKE '%".$searchq."%' OR category2 LIKE '%".$searchq."%' OR category3 LIKE '%".$searchq."%' OR category4 LIKE '%".$searchq."%' OR category5 LIKE '%".$searchq."%'");
      $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
      if($count == 0)
      {
          $output = "There's no search result";
      }
 else {
          while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
            {

             echo $row['name'];

            }

      }
  }
  ?>
```