# Searching for a keyword across multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have a set of names of institutes stored in each row in my schools table. the same table has four different category columns which store the names of the subjects they offer. i want to enable a a functionality where the user conducts a search on the table to find out all the names of the institutes which teach a particular subject (for eg: physics). The name of the particular subject could be stored in any of the four `category` columns. Please suggest a mysqli_/mysql_ query to conduct such a search or if you may so please, suggest a PHP script that would achieve the above functionality. 

EDIT: I am mentioning the table structure below: 
[Table showing column values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3Nfl.png) 
[Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoKe1.png)

Adding all the different queries i have tried with no result:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM institutes WHERE MATCH(category1, category2, category3, category4) AGAINST('$searchq' IN BOOLEAN MODE)") or die(" No records found.");
```

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM institutes WHERE $searchq IN(category1, category2, category3, category4)") or die(" No records found.");
```

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM institutes WHERE category1 LIKE '%$searchq%' OR category2 LIKE '%$searchq%' OR category3 LIKE '%$searchq%' OR category4 LIKE '%$searchq%' OR category5 LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die(" No records found.");
```

The search form:

```
<div class="row col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="input-group">
                <form action="search_results.php" method = "post">
                    <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by subjects...">

                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button submit">Go!</button>
                </span>
                </form>

            </div><!-- /input-group -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

The entire PHP code:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "secretpassword") or die("could not connect.");
    mysql_select_db("edhoc") or die("could not find database.");
    $result = "";

    //collect info from database
    if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
      $searchq = $_POST['search'];
      $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchq);
      //echo $searchq;

      //SQL query
      $query = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM institutes WHERE category1 = '$searchq' OR category2 = '$searchq' OR category3 = '$searchq' OR category4 = '$searchq' OR category5 = '$searchq'") or die(" No records found.");
      $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
      if($count == 0) {
          $output = "There's no search result";
      } else {
          while($array = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
?>
              <li><?php echo $array['name'];?></li>
<?php
          }
      }
    }
?>
```

None of them produce the desired output.
When `physics` is the search string the current output is:

> physics No records found.

When `physics` is the search string, the desired output is:

- Bansal Classes Study Center
- Resonance Eduventures Pvt Ltd

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching across multiple columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36371155/searching-across-multiple-columns)

Comment: This is the third time within 24 hours that you ask that very same question. This (asking the same question multiple times) is considered very rude here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @NineBerry i apologize. i had no intention of being rude. If at all, i am being desperate.

Comment: 1. See normalisation. Desperately.

Comment: If you enable echo $searchq what is the output? I suspect it is empty. Either no input is sent to the form with the name search or you are simply editing the wrong file. Add an echo with some string like "test" to see whether you are actually working on the file that  is executed.

Comment: @NineBerry i have added the output after implementing your instruction to the end of the question. The color to the text was added AFTER i pasted it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following command:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT ....") or die("No records found.");
```

However, when the die part is executed (as seems to be the case because "No records found" is output), then this does not mean that no record was found. It means that there was an error executing the sql statement. So either there is an error in the sql statement or there is a problem with the database connection. Modify the line like this to get a specific error message:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT ....") or die(mysql_error());
```

Since the sql statement fails and yet you still get the same five institute names listed (even before the error message) this means that the list of institute names you see does not come from the php code in your question but from somewhere else.

Comment: You helped me fix it, well almost. But first, i will come clean on my mistakes. The included file that stored the database had a select statement of its own which lead to all the insti names printed as soon as a connection was established. Next, I removed the category5 check from the code which i had carelessly forgotten to remove after i had deleted the "category5" column from the database. After doing the necessary code correction i get correct output but for one thing. above the output, there's the text "1Resource id #6" Why does it show and How do i remove that?

Comment: The output "1Resource id #6" means that somewhere you echo a variable that is the return value of a function like mysql_connect() or mysql_query() so look for places where you echo variables that were returned from these kinds of functions.

Comment: Both were careless mistakes and I apologize wasting everybody's time. I will try to post more intellectual questions in the future.  And somewhere down the line when I gain enough reputation, i will come back here and upvote your answer. Thank you, and i hope you can imagine how relieved i am. Note to other new users: Don't post thank you messages.

Answer (score 1):

We don't likely answer because you don't give a table structure that is easily readable , so I'm going to assume one .

```
Select school from schooltable where subject1=? or subject2=? or subject3=?
```

? Is the search query , if you weren't able to implement it in php reply here and I'll write it for you . 
If I didn't got you , it's your problem you didn't explain enough.

Comment: i have edited the question and added as much information as possible (along with the table structures). Yes, if you could write a php code obtaining the desired result, its going to be a relief.

Comment: Did you try the one I posted ?

Comment: Try it like that query = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM institutes WHERE category1 = '%$searchq%' OR
                                                              category2 = '%$searchq%' OR
                                                              category3 = '%$searchq%' OR 
                                                              category4 = '%$searchq%' OR
                                                              category5 = '%$searchq%'") 
                                                              or die(" No records found.");

Comment: No luck. I have now added the entire PHP code in the question. I am beginning to believe there's fault somewhere else and not the query. Do you think there's a problem with the database itself? Do you think my PHP code is wrong?

Comment: could you please upload the database and provide a link here , i think there's a problem with it .

Comment: here [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53f102) <br>

note: i have now also added the html form (designed with bootstrap) in the question.